# Arrays in JavaScript - How can I save my scanned value in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I created a scannerfunction for my application. For now there are only QR-Codes available but I need only a part of it. The QR Code has e.g. the value 044400000 and the part with the 4's would the part I need.

I thought about taking the QR-Code value and save it an array and select e.g. the index 1,2,3 in this case.

**My first question would be, how can I save a value in an array in javascript so every number has its own index?**

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

If the QR code is a string:

```
$array = Array.from($qrCode);
```

If it is a integer:

```
$array = Array.from($qrCode.toString());
```